# Connection time out while reading contents from a server

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

Hi Here's  what i am trying to  do .

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://123.34.56.123:3000/?location=Example'); //Not the original ip 
//Node script running on port 3000
```

Everything is working  fine on localhost and when i access this url directly  from browser but on my web server i ma getting this error

```
file_get_contents(http://123.34.56.123:3000/?location=Example) Failed to open stream: Connection timed out in ....
```

And i have tried connecting  with curl , sockets and file stream but everything getting the connection is timing  out though it's working  fine on my  local server

I have also used `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` but it didn't help anything

Note :  `file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');` Works fine on the web server

Anyone can  help me  understand  why i am getting this  error ? i have tried almost  everything i could  to  fix this issue.

Comment: is the IP a public one? e.g. it won't work if it's private IP inside your network, and the machine running this code is somewhere OUTSIDE your network.

Comment: @MarcB but i can access it directly from my browser and it's  working  fine  from my local server too  so that  means  it's a public ip  right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the server i was using was  blocking connection on port 3000 , and  it  makes  complete sense  as normally web host use 80 and 443 port only to make i/o connection . I contacted with my web host  they  unlocked  the 3000 port and  it's  working perfectly  now  .

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check that whether the content which you are fetching from resource is encoded or not, means if the content is encoded with JSON then you need to use json script to decode it and after that you will be able to be get the content..

also check the resource URL and the port of the server that you are using.
If your port 3000 is blocked then it also not works fine.

I though it will help you.

Comment: I said it's working  fine  on my localserver just not working on my web server  on my web server and  the output is also not a json object